VB.NET con LiveCharts
Quiero implementar un gráfico de líneas con LiveChart, pero no he logrado cargarlo con los datos provenientes del datatable. Toda la consulta está en el procedimiento almacenado, por lo que el resultado de la consulta viene lista (muestra la cantidad de venta por hora):

Estas líneas son sólo de pruebas tratando de seguir ejemplos visto en la web:
Dim dtb As New DataTable

    dtb = oVTA.BusquedaVenta("ResumenporHora").Tables("Tabla")

    If dtb.Rows.Count > 0 Then

          Dim labelPoint As Func(Of ChartPoint, String) = Function(chartPoint) String.Format("{0} ({0})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation)

        Dim piechartData As SeriesCollection = New SeriesCollection()

        For Each fila As DataRow In dtb.Rows()

            piechartData.Add(New PieSeries With {
            .Title = Convert.ToString(fila("TOTAL")).ToString(),
            .Values = New ChartValues(Of Integer) From {
                Convert.ToInt32(fila("TOTAL"))
            },
            .DataLabels = True,
            .LabelPoint = labelPoint
        })
        Next

        chrtGrafic.Series = piechartData
        chrtGrafic.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right

    End If
End Sub


Luego de revisar varias páginas y videos, logré mostrar mi gráfico de LiveCharts. Seguí los pasos de este tutorial por si alguien le sirve:
https://youtu.be/Hylna_NfmR8?si=cjN7LFqxAvjKocvV
